# Why does comparing those two things gives different results?

Tags: assembly, x86, tasm, dosbox

I have an array of bytes named col1, and his first 4 elements are equal to 1. Now, I tried to compare

```
cmp [col1+1], 1
JE my_label
```

And this indeed jumped to my_label (i.e they are equal). 
However, when I tried to compare

```
cmp [offset col1 + 1], 1
JE my_label
```

It didn't jump to my_label, which means they are not equal. How is it possible? shouldn't offset col1 be the address of the first element in the array, and then offset col1 + 1 is the address of the second element in the array, which is indeed equal to 1?

Comment: You can answer some of this yourself with experimentation: You can simplify by isolating the addressing mode usages from the compare & branch operation. Try moving the two values associated with the memory addressing modes into a register and examine what you get.

Comment: What machine code instruction does `cmp [offset col1 + 1], 1` even assemble to?  Did that maybe defeat some default operand-size that makes this otherwise ambiguous code work, and maybe you ended up doing a `cmp word ptr [mem16], imm8`?

Comment: with your debugger you can display the disassembled code. If you disassemble both variants, what is the difference?